# How to open array of links correctly?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a question, how do I open all link from an array at the same time, not only one like it does now, I've tried something like this:

```js
var urls = ["https://www.google.com", "https://www.facebook.com"];
let main = function() {
 for (var i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {
  window.open(urls[i], '_blank');
 }
};
main();
```

Can anybody show some examples? Thanks! :p

Comment: Chrome and possibly other browsers will block popups if more than one are attempted to be opened right after each other, check that it isnt doing that (should be an icon at the end of the address bar indicating it)

Comment: Ok, it worked! :) Thanks

Comment: @PatrickEvans Out of curiosity, is there documentation on this? I'm wondering what defines "right after each other"?

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
            var urls = ["https://www.google.com", "https://www.facebook.com"];
            function main() {
                for (var i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {
                    var el = document.querySelector('#hidden') ;
                    //window.open(urls[i], '_blank');
                    var a = document.createElement('a');
                    a.href = urls[i];
                    a.target = '_blank';
                    el.appendChild(a);
                    a.click();
                }
            }
            window.addEventListener('load', function () { main();}, !1);
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id='hidden'></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: :D why the `!1`?? isn't `0` simpler? BTW it's `false` by default; and `window.addEventListener('load', main)` is even shorter.

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/350567) by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.